# In postfix can I add message-id to another header?

Tags: postfix, centos7

I'm trying to PREPEND the message-id on another header using variable for example.

/^From:/ PREPEND VAR_Message-id

is this possible. excuse my ignorance i'm new to postfix

Comment: Why? What problem would that solve?

Comment: For google Feedback loop.  so i can identify user in google's postmaster tool

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. by adding $1 to header_check file i.e. 
PREPEND HEADER: $1